# Should I learn MySQL and SQL server together for learning SQL?

Tags: database, mysql, sql, sql-server

I am starting to learn SQL so I was wondering which RDBMS should I use, i.e. MySQL or SQL Server, so I can also mention that tool in my resume to give good impression to get a job here in India.

So can I learn both this RDBMS together...???

Comment: Hi prasad_21, welcome to [softwarerecs.se]! This question does not appear to be about software recommendations, within [the scope defined on meta](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scope) and in the [help center](/help/on-topic). If you think you can [edit] it to become on-topic, please have a look at the [question quality guidelines](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/23377).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, SQL server used with Microsoft technologies and Mysql used with Java technologies. If you want to become a developer choose the RDMS based on technology that you want to go with it, but if you want to go into the administration field (not software development) focus on one of them and take advance experience knowledge by practical practice.

Comment: for development path in Mysql you can check these topics in this [tutorial](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/) and for administration check this [tutorial](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-administration.aspx)

Comment: By the way, my above answer not related to specific country my answer in general.

Comment: Yeah, my main focus is for development, but can I learn both MySql and Sql Sever together, or if it would confuse me...??

Comment: Focus on one of them after you become professional in it go to another (this is my point of view )